# $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{D}_X)$ and $\mathcal{M}^r(\mathcal{D}_X)$ have natural tensor category structures?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, d-modules

Write $\mathcal{M}^\ell(\mathcal{D}_{X/S}) = \mathcal{M}(\mathcal{D}_{X/S})$ for the category of left $\mathcal{D}$-modules over $X$ and $\mathcal{M}^r(\mathcal{D}_{X/S})$ for the category of right $\mathcal{D}$-modules over $X$. How do I see that $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{D}_X)$ and $\mathcal{M}^r(\mathcal{D}_X)$ have natural tensor category structures?

Comment: Do you happen to know they do have it?

Comment: Is $X \to S$ smooth?

Comment: Here's a simple case: if $A = \mathcal D(\mathbb A^n)$ is the Weyl algebra, the tensor product of $M$ and $N$ is given by $M \otimes_\mathcal{O} N$, where the $A$ module structure is $a\cdot (x\otimes y) = (a\cdot x)\otimes y + x\otimes(a\cdot y)$. It's easy to check the relations for $A$. I don't know what hypotheses are necessary for this to hold in general.